# status messages from background ruby script

Tags: ruby

I have a Ruby script runned as daemon, but isn't a daemon. It grabs tasks from a database and processes them. I want to monitor this script from a PHP web front-end and display status messages such as "works fine", "have N problems", etc.

How I can do this without using daemon gems? Is it possible?

Comment: considered having a look at beanstalkd (http://kr.github.com/beanstalkd/) (with beaneater gem) ? There are multiple PHP front-ends for monitoring.

Comment: Thanks, but too hard, I would like something simpler.

Comment: Hm.. maybe i can use memcache? for example sets the one key, named "important-ruby-worker", which will be contain status message?
how I hadn't thought of?

Answer (score 0):

PHP provides the `exec` function to run arbitrary commands. You can use it to check whether the desired process is failing or running. You can do something like:

```
<?php 
  $ruby_command = 'ruby check_status.rb 2>&1' ;
 $out = exec($ruby_command);
?>
```

Check the output and do what you wanted to do. What's the problem with that?